# Jquery : What the event Should we call in this sitaution for an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form  "B" where we get all the detaills for the elements from  form  "A" i mean request flows from  "A "to "B" .For one Element 
we need to call  call the Ajax request and get the Assocaited details . Now we are  sending the ajax request  for "change" event .
Which event needs to be used inorder to satisfy both.Can we use onload, change .It did not work out

```
$("#txt1").bind('change load', function() {
    var dstvalue = $("#txt1").val();
    if (dstvalue.length < 3) {
        $("#err").text("characters");
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $.getJSON("ajax.php", {
        'term': $("#txt1").val()
    }, function(data) {
        $("#err").text($.trim(data[0].label));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler just after bunding it in your `ready` handler to satisfy the `load` event, like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false});
$(function() {
  $("#txt1").change(function(){
    var dstvalue = $(this).val();
    if(dstvalue.length < 3) {
      $("#err").text("characters");
    }
    $.getJSON("ajax.php",{'term' : dstvalue}, function (data) {
        $("#err").text($.trim(data[0].label));
    });
  }).change(); //call it on ready
});
```

Comment: Iam able to get the Correct Value passed to the "#err" when i input the value and it is not working when the value coming from other form

Answer (score 0):

So, I gather you want to fire the ajax request once when the page loads, and again if the value of #txt1 changes?

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getDetails() {
        var dstvalue = $("#txt1").val();
        if (dstvalue.length < 3) {
            $("#err").text("characters");
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $.getJSON("ajax.php", { 'term': $("#txt1").val() }, function(data) {
            $("#err").text($.trim(data[0].label));
        });
    }

    $("#txt1").change(getDetails);
    getDetails();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding events on a input of type "text" it doesn't have the onLoad that's why you can't bind. You can bind it with focus instead, that's occur when the input receive the focus.

If you want to send an Ajax when the document is ready, you should use $(document).ready() instead.